# Using std::for_each on polymorphic method in c++

Tags: c++, stl, vector, polymorphism, foreach

When using the std::for_each,

```
class A;
vector<A*> VectorOfAPointers;

std::for_each(VectorOfAPointers.begin(), VectorOfAPointers.end(), std::mem_fun(&A::foo));
```

If we have classes inheriting from A and implementing foo(), and we hold a vector of pointers to A,
is there any way to call a polymorphic call on foo(), rather then explicitly calling A::foo()?
Note: I can't use boost, only standard STL.

Thanks,
Gal

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It actually works this way.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    virtual void foo() {
        std::cout << "A::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};
struct B: public A {
    virtual void foo() {
        std::cout << "B::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A*> VectorOfAPointers;
    VectorOfAPointers.push_back(new B());
    std::for_each(VectorOfAPointers.begin(), VectorOfAPointers.end(), std::mem_fun(&A::foo));
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
B::foo()
```

So it does exactly what you want. Check that `virtual` keywords are present though, it's easy to forget them.